# how to concatenate value of dropdown list

Tags: c#

I have three dropdown lists. From these three I have to select various path to retrieve one folder. The problem is path can't retrieve the folder and give error can't find a part of path. My code for that is.

```
protected void Btn_Load_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)


    {

        string _username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImpersonatedUserName"].ToString();
        string _password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImpersonatedPassword"].ToString();
        string _domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImpersonatedDomain"].ToString();

        Impersonation objImpersonation = new Impersonation();

        if (objImpersonation.impersonateValidUser(_username, _domain, _password))
        {




        string PathFecha = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.ToString() + "\\Convert.ToString(Drp_List1.SelectedItem)\\Convert.ToString(Drp_List2.SelectedItem)\\Convert.ToString(Drp_List3.SelectedItem)\\";

            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(PathFecha);
            foreach (string filename in files)
            {
              ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename), filename));

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not converting the paths properly.

**Change this line:**

```
string PathFecha = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.ToString() + "\\Convert.ToString(Drp_List1.SelectedItem)\\Convert.ToString(Drp_List2.SelectedItem)\\Convert.ToString(Drp_List3.SelectedItem)\\";
```

**TO:**

```
string PathFecha = string.Format("{0}{4}{1}{4}{2}{4}{3}{4}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.ToString(), Drp_List1.SelectedText, Drp_List2.SelectedText, Drp_List3.SelectedText, "\\");
```

Comment: `.net 4.0` overload `Path.Combine Method (String[])` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142%28VS.100%29.aspx might be helpful here too

Answer (score 0):

Use `Drp_List1.SelectedItem.Text` if you need `Text` of selected dropdown menu item.

Use `Drp_List1.SelectedItem.Value` if you need `Value` of selected dropdown menu.

Do this for all dropdowns.

Comment: how to set both Text and Value  property for selected dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks to me that with this line:

```
string PathFecha = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.ToString() + "\\Convert.ToString(Drp_List1.SelectedItem)\\Convert.ToString(Drp_List2.SelectedItem)\\Convert.ToString(Drp_List3.SelectedItem)\\";
```

you are simply concatenating a single string to the base path, which is not what you want. Putting C# code into a string won't replace the result of that code in the string. What you want to do is concatenate each part of the path individually:

```
string PathFecha = Convert.ToString(Drp_List1.SelectedItem) + "\\"
                   + Convert.ToString(Drp_List2.SelectedItem) + "\\"
                   + Convert.ToString(Drp_List3.SelectedItem) + "\\";
```

And, as Gloria said, if you want to use the text of the selected item, you should use `Drp_List1.SelectedItem.Text`. So it should actually be:

```
string PathFecha = Drp_List1.SelectedItem.Text + "\\"
                   + Drp_List2.SelectedItem.Text + "\\"
                   + Drp_List3.SelectedItem.Text + "\\";
```

Comment: Any of the above suggestions are not working.can you please provide anything else.

Comment: none of solution is working, it gives the compilation error that Could not find a part of the path as before.Can you guys provide other solutions plz.

Comment: Well, you need to make sure that the path does actually exist. If you want to check, then after your declaration of PathFecha, you can write: MessageBox.Show(PathFecha); so that you can see what path it thinks it's looking at.

Comment: I have a listbox to show folder from the given path, in the error shows the right path but also says"Could not find a part of the path".The actual path does exist.

Comment: in the actual path there is one url smthg like this \\192.168.100.22\MerData\ErrorLog\Lun\Website but in error page shows System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\System.Configuration.KeyValueInternalCollection\192.168.100.22\MerData\ErrorLog\Lun\Website'.

Comment: I fixed the problem thanks @Jashaszun ,I have to remove  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.ToString() + "\\" and its working fine.

Comment: @user253029 If this was the correct answer, then it would be appreciated if you marked it as such. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 string PathFecha = 
    System.IO.Path.Combine(
     ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.ToString(),
     Drp_List1.SelectedItem.Text,
     Drp_List2.SelectedItem.Text,
     Drp_List3.SelectedItem.Text);
```

Using Path.Combine() may make it a little easier dealing with the paths.